# How to count the number of people who choose a particular location?

Tags: mysql, sql

i need help in select sql statement.

in my mysql database:

location table

```
serialID(AI)|locations | telephone | address
---------------------------------------------
1           | A       
2           | B
3           | C
4           | D

users table
userID | location chosen
-------------------------
1      | A
2      | B
3      | B
```

I want to count the number of people who choose a particular location and display in the table. So if this particular location have more users choosen as their favourite location, it will move up to the first row. May I know how can I do this?

something like this when it populate into dynamic table ->

```
location | address | telephone | user's favourable
B        |  -      | -         |  2
A        |  -      | -         |  1
C        |  -      | -         |  0
D        |   -     | -         |  0
```

Comment: I think you missed the code of [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Plz, use a foreign key: location_id in users table instead of  varchar attribute 'location chosen', it is more efficient.

Comment: Never mind "more efficient", foreign keys enforce data integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a query like this:

```
SELECT l.locations, l.telephone, l.address, COUNT (u.userID) as `location_count`
FROM location AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS u on l.locations = u.location_chosen
GROUP BY l.locations
ORDER BY `location_count` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  loc.*, countResult.usersFavourable
FROM    location loc
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  locationChoosen, COUNT(*) `usersFavourable`
            FROM    users
            GROUP BY    locationChoosen
        ) countResult ON loc.locations = countResult.locationChoosen
ORDER BY countResult.usersFavourable DESC, loc.locations
```

Comment: No need for a subselect here

Comment: There's no reason not to do one either.  Both forms are perfectly acceptable.  In some databases, this will perform better than doing the  join first.  @JW . . . I do wish you used sensible aliases, such as "l" for lcoations rather than "a".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  l.location, l.address, l.telephone, COUNT(u.userID) AS [users favourable]
FROM    location l
        LEFT JOIN
            users u
            ON l.location = u.locationchosen
GROUP BY l.location, l.address, l.telephone
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select count(userId) count,locations,address,telephone 
from Table1 Left join Table2 
on Table1.locations = Table2.location

group by locations order by count desc ;
```

see here.. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ea50/15/0)

Answer (score -2):

```
 SELECT LocationChosen, Count(*) FROM usersTable GROUP BY LocationChosen
```

Comment: Because the OP wants a count for unchosen locations too

Comment: EDIT- Guess you were talking about my answer. yes, if you want unchosen locations as well, see all of the other answers as mine just gives you locations that are chosen